# Selecting previous item in dropdown

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm building a database search engine in Laravel and I am having some problems getting Laravel to select the previously selected item in a dropdown.

Using the template builder options I can make the select like this, and it does what I want it to do:

```
{{ Form::select('bomserial', $bomserials, Input::get('bomserial'), array('class' => 'pure-input-1', 'tabindex' => '3')) }}
```

The "Input::Get('bomserial')" makes it re-select the previously selected option in the dropdown after the form has been submitted, but building the input this way means I can't use the "selected disabled" option, so I opted to build the select like this instead:

```
<select name="bomserial" class="pure-input-1" tabindex="3">
    <option selected disabled>BOM Serial</option>
    @foreach ($bomserials as $bomserial)
    <option value="{{ $bomserial->serial }}">{{ $bomserial->serial }} - {{ $bomserial->job_desc }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This produces a better looking menu and allows for the use of a default option, but now I can no longer re-select the previous option after the form has been submitted. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using the Form builder anymore, you have to manually take control of selecting the correct option.

Based on your existing logic, you're looking at something like this: if the bomserial is not in the input, select the placeholder; if the bomserial is in the input, select the bomserial option that matches the input.

```
<select name="bomserial" class="pure-input-1" tabindex="3">
    <option {{ Input::has('bomserial') ? '' : 'selected' }} disabled>BOM Serial</option>
    @foreach ($bomserials as $bomserial)
    <option value="{{ $bomserial->serial }}" {{ Input::get('bomserial') == $bomserial->serial ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $bomserial->serial }} - {{ $bomserial->job_desc }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```